# How to define our own type in Julia?

Tags: julia

```
Julia> type Circle
    ERROR: syntax: extra token "Circle" after end of expression
Stack trace:
 [1] top-level scope at none:0
```

I already tried struct method but it's not working as per requirements.

Comment: Put your code here, please. This is the type of question you could consult the software user manual of your resource.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say you want to define your own `Circle` type and you choose to represent circles by giving their radius and center (`(x, y)` for simplicity .. 3D coords follow the same pattern of definition). The first thing to decide is whether or not you want to be able to change some value of a `Circle` once created.  Let's assume you want to be able to move its center once created.

- To create a type that has changeable field values, we use a `mutable struct`
- To define a field for our type we give it a name and specify its type
- To construct a realization of our type, we use a function of the same name

```
mutable struct Circle
    radius::Float64
    xcoord::Float64
    ycoord::Float64
end

circle1 = Circle(inv(2pi), 0.0, 0.0)
circle2 = Circle(sqrt(2.0), 1.0, 1.0)
```

then

```
julia> circle1 = Circle(inv(2pi), 0.0, 0.0)
Circle(0.15915494309189535, 0.0, 0.0)

julia> circle2 = Circle(sqrt(2.0), 1.0, 1.0)
Circle(1.4142135623730951, 1.0, 1.0)

# and we can move the Circles
julia> circle2.xcoord = 0.0
julia> circle2.ycoord = 0.0
julia> circle2
Circle(1.4142135623730951, 0.0, 0.0)

# and we can change the radius if need be
julia> circle.radius = 1.0
julia> circle2
Circle(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

Now, we can do a better (neater, clearer) job of it.  We may choose to define a 2D Point type (or a 3D Point type), and use that for a field type within `Circle`.  And once we have this type, there are a few embellishments you probably want to incorporate.

```
diameter(x::Circle) = 2 * x.radius
circumference(x::Circle) = pi * diameter(x)
```

and you can show it more clearly

```
Base.show(io::IO, x::Circle) =
   print(io, string("Circle(radius=",x.radius, " x=",x.xcoord, " y=",x.ycoord,")"))
```

then

```
julia> circle2
Circle(radius=1.4142135623730951 x=0.0 y=0.0)
```

For custom types where the field values do not change follow the same pattern replacing `mutable struct` with `struct` (omit the `mutable`).  And, of course, there are more advanced techniques that can be applied see in the docs:

- [Types](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/)

Please feel free ask any follow-up questions you may have.

Answer (score 6):

You can declare a new (composite) type with `struct`:

```
julia> struct Circle end

julia> Circle()
Circle()
```

Also check out the [documentation on types](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/).